# Make input field mandatory based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I select A,B,C input field is not mandotory.If I select C,test input box should be mandatory.
I tried but its not working.

HTML:

```
<select name="test" id="select" onclick="selection()">
<option value="">A</option> 
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="nil">nil</option>
    </select> 
<td>test</td>                           
<td><input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" />
 <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="selection()" />
```

JS:

```
function selection()
{
 var cat = document.getElementById('select').value;
    if (cat == "nil") {
        if (document.getElementById("test1").value == "") {
            alert('Mandatory');

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have two `id` attributes: `id="test"` and `id="select"`, try to remove `id="test"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event for select.
[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/jomcv57r/1/)

**HTML**

```
<select name="test" id="select" onchange="selection()">
<option value="">A</option> 
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="nil">nil</option>
    </select> 
<td>test</td>                           
<td><input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" />
 <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="selection()" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function selection()
{    
 var cat = document.getElementById('select').value;    
    if (cat == "nil") {
        if (document.getElementById("test1").value == "") {
            alert('Mandatory');
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

**[Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/jomcv57r/1/)**

Comment: @coder_tech - `upvote` the answer will helps other to find out correct solutions. Glad to Help you :)

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Comment: It works in Jsfiddle.But applying in my code,it doesn't work.WHY?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onchange` instead of `onclick` and `if (cat == "C")` instead of `if(cat == "nil")`

```js
function selection()
{
 var cat = document.getElementById('select').value;
    if (cat == "C") {
        if (document.getElementById("test1").value == "") {
            alert('Mandatory');
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<select name="test" id="select" onchange="selection()">
    <option value="">A</option> 
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="nil">nil</option>
</select> 

<td>test</td>                           
<td><input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" onchange="selection()" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="selection()" />
```

Additionally, you need to use `input onchange="selection()"` to detect if the user has cleared the input when `c` is selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <script>
 $(document).delegate("#select","change",function(e){
        if ($(this).val() === 'C')
            $('#save').attr('onclick','chk()');

        else
           $('#save').removeAttr('onclick');
    });
 function chk()
 {
    var name=$('#name').val();

    if(name=="")
    {
        alert("Mr. Hussy Please fill this box");

    }
 }
</script>

<select name="test" id="select">
<option value="">A</option> 
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="nil">nil</option>
    </select> 
<td>test</td>                           
<td><input type="text" name="test1" id="name" />
 <input id='save' type="button" value="submit" />
    </body>
</html>
```